# How to format tabular data WITHOUT row labels?

Tags: python, formatting

For instance right now the output is:

```
                Temp [C]   v [m3/kg]   u [kJ/kg]  s [kJ/kgK]
    Temp [C]           1           2           1           3
   v [m3/kg]           0           1           0           3
   u [kJ/kg]           2           4           2           3
  s [kJ/kgK]           2           4           2           3
```

and I want it to look like:

```
    Temp [C]   v [m3/kg]   u [kJ/kg]  s [kJ/kgK]
    1           2           1           3
    0           1           0           3
    2           4           2           3
    2           4           2           3
```

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
units = ['Temp [C]', 'v [m3/kg]', 'u [kJ/kg]', 's [kJ/kgK]']
data = ([1, 2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 0, 3], [2, 4, 2,3], [2, 4, 2,3])

format_row = "{:>12}" * (len(units) + 1)
print(format_row.format("", *units))
for unit, row in zip(units, data):
    print(format_row.format(unit, *row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
units = ['Temp [C]', 'v [m3/kg]', 'u [kJ/kg]', 's [kJ/kgK]']
data = ([1, 2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 0, 3], [2, 4, 2,3], [2, 4, 2,3])

fmt_string = '{:<15}' * len(units)
print(fmt_string.format(*units))
for row in data:
    print(fmt_string.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
Temp [C]        v [m3/kg]       u [kJ/kg]       s [kJ/kgK]     
1               2               1               3              
0               1               0               3              
2               4               2               3              
2               4               2               3
```

Comment: When I try to make it right justified ( fmt_string = '{:>15}' * len(units) ), my output is shifted to the right INCLUDING the beginning. How do I fix this?

Comment: @quilicam You can change it `fmt_string = '{:<15}' * len(units)` it will shift to left